# Is it possible to use Travis CI to push a subdirectory from one Git repo into another?

Tags: git, github, continuous-integration, travis-ci

This may seem like an odd request but hear me out... I maintain a framework called Kickoff (https://github.com/tmwagency/kickoff) and every time I push to the master I would like to push one or a few subdirectories to other Kickoff-related repos that I also maintain. These are https://github.com/tmwagency/kickoff-statix and https://github.com/tmwagency/generator-kickoff. In both cases I would like the `scss` directory to be pushed to the other repos. This would cut out some manual labour and hopefully allow the two other repos to always be up-to-date.

I have Travis setup already, but I am not familiar enough with git internals to know if this is possible. If it is not, is there another way for me to achieve what I want?

Many thanks

Comment: Did you set up the additions projects as git-submodules?

Comment: No, nothing is in a submodule at the moment. It is the other route that I think I will be exploring if I cannot do what I would like...

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to integrate your sub-projects as [git-submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5252450/using-someone-elses-repo-as-a-git-submodule-on-github).

Using submodules you could use the [`after_success`](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/build-configuration/#Build-Lifecycle)-hook for a push by opening the submodule-directory and invoking a `git push`.

Travis-CI also supports the [build-cycle-update of your submodules](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/build-configuration/#Git-Submodules) which pulls the changes in the submodules into your super-project. But it sounds like you just want to push your stuff out of the build.

Comment: Thanks @florianb, I thought I would need to use submodules. One question though, are you suggesting that my other projects (generator-kickoff and kickoff-statix) are the submodules or the `scss` directory? Thanks again

Comment: Hi @Zander, i would reflect the real world-dependencies. So if your `scss/`-directory is going to be used in several other projects this might be a hint to let it become a submodule.

Comment: I think you're right but I think I'd rather keep everything together than not. Cheers again

Comment: @Zander - you're welcome. I must confess that creating a sub-directory no elegant way to handle your problem - the way submodules work is often criticized. Another solution could be a partial merge-in from your subprojects, using `git read-tree` which allows your sub-projects to merge directories in. Since you're looking for a travis-triggered solution, it may be difficult to implement a build-trigger.

Comment: just had a look at `git read-tree`, it might be just what I need. Thanks