# Give permissions on project folder in github

Tags: github

I have 10 main folders in this project I want to give access to the external team just in one sub-folder in my git repository so that they can make changes and submit a Pull Request.

Is there a way of doing it? If not, can you please suggest a better way?

Answer (score 16):

There is no such access-rights-mechanism implemented on GitHub repositories out of the box.

### Using a [submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)

Using a submodule does the trick, and is pretty much easy to set up. You can give the customers full access to the submodule repository, while you add it to your main project repository.

Note that the StackOverflow question ["Using someone else's repo as a Git Submodule on GitHub"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5252450/using-someone-elses-repo-as-a-git-submodule-on-github) and [its answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5252450/using-someone-elses-repo-as-a-git-submodule-on-github?answertab=votes#tab-top) are also worth reading.

This is in my opinion the most simple and straightforward way to do it.

### Using a webhook

If you really don't want to use submodules, you can still restrict access rights by creating a [GitHub webhook](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/about-webhooks) that implements this mechanism. The [Git SCM documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-An-Example-Git-Enforced-Policy) explains how to do that part.

Answer (score 12):

## Using the "codeowners" feature

This is free for public repositories and paid for private repositories.

#### Step 1: Define code owners

Code owners are defined by adding a file named *CODEOWNERS* to the root of your repository.

Syntax:

```
# <directory or file filter> <user or group>

# Examples:

README.md @octocat
/veryimportant/ @myorganization/teamname
```

Documentation: https://docs.github.com/en/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/about-code-owners

#### Step 2: Restrict Pull Requests

With paid github subscriptions, PRs can be restricted in a way that a review by a code owner is required before merging it:

[image]

#### Result

Having this configured, pull requests with changes to the locations / files / directories configured via the `CODEOWNERS` file require a code owner review. Screenshot:

[image]

#### Step 3: Restrict Admins

Admins and owners would still be able to commit directly to `master`. It is therefore recommended to apply the branch restrictions to Admins as well:

[image]

Comment: If you take this approach, you'd also want your main branch protected so that it's not possible for anyone to just push to master directly. Note that is *not* the same as the "Include administrators" setting listed above.

Answer (score 0):

With modern Git that have Sparse checkout and [partial clones](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/git/partial_clone.html) I believe that it could be achieved using some kind of Git hooks. I did run some experiments [here](https://github.com/smulikHakipod/git-subfolder-permssions) where I used some kind of Git hooks and HTTP reverse proxy + the use Git sparse checkout to allow access to only certain subfolders. This is just an experiment though.