# Add different sub folders to different git repository from Vscode?

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

I have a folder structure like

```
Project
|----SERVER
|----CLIENT
```

and I want to add server folder to its own repo and client folder to its own repo for hosting purpose, and the main project folder in its own repo so it is easier to share with other people. I initialized a GitHub repo in all three location but Vscode only accepts the main project folder in its source control, but if I open client and server folders in separate window then only it shows up in the source control tab. Is there any way I can commit, push and pull in all three repos using one window?

Comment: As you noticed, you may not be able to adequately work with `Project` folder if you have 3 separate repositories. Use submodule feature of git. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40567468/give-permissions-on-project-folder-in-github shows some strategies.

Comment: Work with a Multi Root Workspace, then each workspace can have its own `.git` folder and the SCM bar of VSC will handle it correct